# Оптимизация слайдера

Tags: javascript

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/PBZBW/) сам слайдер. Чтоб переместить ползунок использую событие mousemove, и при медленном перетягивании ползунка все работает нормально. Но когда скорость намного больше то получаются резкие перепады и он работает неадекватно.
Можно ли оптимизировать код чтоб нагрузка на js была небольшая и он работал нормально?

Comment: дергается, потому что за пределы вылетает, вот получше

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PBZBW/1/

Comment: я так делал, но мне нужна оптимизация. Или оно не особо напрягает браузер?

Comment: типа так ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PBZBW/2/